# why my get<k>() function cannot receive subclass of tuple?

Tags: c++, c++11

I copied a tuple implementation online, and it works find for most case:

```
template<class... Ts>
class tuple {};

template<class T, class... Ts>
class tuple<T, Ts...> : public tuple<Ts...> {
 public:
  tuple(T t, Ts... ts) : tuple<Ts...>(ts...), tail(t) {}
  T tail;
};

template<size_t, class>
struct elem_type_holder;

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct elem_type_holder<0, tuple<T, Ts...>> {
  typedef T type;
};

template<size_t k, class T, class... Ts>
struct elem_type_holder<k, tuple<T, Ts...>> {
  typedef typename elem_type_holder<k - 1, tuple<Ts...>>::type type;
};

template<size_t k, class... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<
    k == 0, typename elem_type_holder<0, tuple<Ts...>>::type &>::type
get(tuple<Ts...> &t) {
  return t.tail;
}

template<size_t k, class T, class... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<
    k != 0, typename elem_type_holder<k, tuple<T, Ts...>>::type &>::type
get(tuple<T, Ts...> &t) {
  tuple<Ts...> &base = t;
  return get<k - 1>(base);
}
```

For example, I wrote code like this:

```
tuple<int, int, int> mytuple(1, 2, 3);
std::cout << get<1>(mytuple) << std::endl;
```

"2" will print.

But I found if I create a subclass which inherit my custom tuple:

```
class Foo : public tuple<int, int, int> {
 public:
  Foo() : tuple<int, int, int>(1, 2, 3) {}
};
```

and create a object for `Foo` in `main()`:

```
Foo foo;
td::cout << get<1>(foo) << std::endl;
```

the `get()` function will not work, the error is:

```
no matching function for call to ‘get<1>(Foo&)’
```

Then I test the `std::tuple` and `std::get()`, subclass of `std::tuple` works fine with `std::get()`.

Currently I have to static_cast it to the tuple class than pass it, this is annoying.

So what did I miss? How can I pass a subclass of my `tuple` like the stl?

Comment: [msvc compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/sjAbAX)

Comment: @StackDanny I tried VS, clang and gcc, seems that only MSVC know the base type, it's weird, since even the reader knows the base type, while the compiler don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g++` tells us:

> ```
> <source>:30:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> <source>:39:15: note:   'tuple<T, Ts ...>' is an ambiguous base class of 'Foo'
>    39 |     get<1>(foo);
>       |               ^
> ```

This is caused by the recursive inheritance nature of:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct tuple<T, Ts...> : tuple<Ts...> { };
```

As the compiler doesn't know what base class to deduce. It could be any of `tuple<int>`, `tuple<int, int>`, or `tuple<int, int, int>`.

In fact, changing the definition to...

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct tuple<T, Ts...> { };
```

...will make the deduction work.

---

One possible fix is redefining your tuple as:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct tuple<T, Ts...> 
{ 
    tuple<Ts...> parent;
};
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aZqRkL)

Comment: That's a terrible problem, This code is just a prototype, the real one is more complicated, I have to use class for some privacy protection and virtual methods, is there any thing I can do beside change `class` to `struct`?

Comment: @reavenisadesk: that change is completely unrelated to your question. It was made just to simplify the code. Please make sure you understand what the problem is - it is about inheritance. Is there any part of my answer that is not clear?

Comment: Then why stl do not have this problem? On my environment the `tuple` is a class.

Comment: @reavenisadesk: because the STL does not use recursive inheritance to implement tuple. `struct` or `class` is completely meaningless here. Read the error message.

Comment: See https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/std/tuple#L492. `libstdc++` uses `_Tuple_impl`, not `tuple` itself during inheritance.